# AllowAnonymous Attribute in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on an older ASP.NET project and debugging in IISExpress and have implemented an API controller method that should require no authentication/anonymous (the project is set to Windows Authentications I believe).

Within APIController, I have added the following attribute above the method:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.AllowAnonymous]
```

Within the web.config file I have added the following with a correct location:

```
<location path="api/GreenTime">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

However, when visiting the API Controller/Method, the browser prompts to credentials and returns a 401.2 error if domain credentials are supplied.

Comment: You say it's an API controller? As in the Web API framework? Did you notice that the attribute you're using is in the MVC namespace (System.Web.Mvc), not in the Web API namespace (System.Web.Http)? You probably want [this attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh835113(v=vs.118)) instead.

Comment: I can also use "System.Web.Http.AllowAnonymous", not sure if this is correct. The Controller inherits from ApiController.

Comment: I just changed to System.Web.Http.AllowAnonymous attribute above the method but same result unfortunately.

Comment: Remove the web.config logic. You're not going to need it.

Comment: @mason If I remove the web.config block like in my OP, then it does not work. I managed to figure it out, see my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue. AnonymousAuthentication was set to false in the VS Project settings. You have to click on the project in the solution explorer and press F4 to find the settings.